# Create one to one relationship with join table in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a many to one relationship from the class client to estimate.

```
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "fkIdClientEstimate", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Estimate> estimateList = new ArrayList<>();
```

But is it possible to create a one to one relationship from estimate to client. I tried something like this but it does not enter any values into the database ?

```
@OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
        name = "tbl_estimate_client",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="id_estimate"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="id_client"))
private Client client ;
```

I also tried it with `private Client client = new client`But it creates a new client into the database instead.

Comment: Show your full persistent classes, please.